# requiring a file throws unexpected error

Tags: include, require, php, require-once

I have a class that I included into another class, but I get an error:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$path' (T_VARIABLE)`

Inside the class the `$path` variable is actually commented out.

Here is part of the class I'm including:

```
class SQLite {

private $name   = '';
private $dir    =  '';
private $handle = '';

public function __construct($class) {
    if(!$class) exit('Must supply class name.');

    $name = $this->name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $class);
    $dir  = $this->dir  = str_replace(basename(__DIR__), 'db', __DIR__);

        #$path = $this->dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->name . '.sqlite3';
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I've tried using `require()`, `include()`, `require_once()` etc, but to no avail. I'm sure the files are being saved. I've tried extending my new class via the one I'm including, and I've also tried creating an instance of it in the new class's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

had `new PDO('sqlite:' $path)` instead of `new PDO('sqlite:' . $path);`